# Merge objects of 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

Lets have a look an example.

`let arr1 = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png"}, {image: "some_image_url_2.png"}]`

`let arr2 = [{value: "some value 1"}, {value: "some value 2"}]`

I need to merge this 2 arrays of objects and create the following array.

`let result = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png", value: "some value 1"},
{image: "some_image_url_2.png", value: "some value 2"}]`

Is there any solution do this with angular 2? Maybe with lodash?

Comment: You should not include thanks for answers in the question itself. You can  do that here in comment.

Answer (score 1):

To generate new array from existing arrays you can use `map()`:

```js
let arr1 = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png"}, {image: "some_image_url_2.png"}]

let arr2 = [{value: "some value 1"}, {value: "some value 2"}]

let result = arr1.map(function(i, idx){
  var obj = {};
  obj.image = i.image; 
  obj.value = arr2[idx].value;
  return obj;
});

console.log(result)
```

```css
[{image: "some_image_url_1.png", value: "some value 1"},
{image: "some_image_url_2.png", value: "some value 2"}]
```

Comment: What if the object in second array have other properties different that `value` or multiple properties?

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution imho. BTW: also more detailed than my answer lol

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary count of arrays and for unequaly length, you could reduce the array and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for the objects.

```js
var array1 = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png"}, {image: "some_image_url_2.png"}],
    array2 = [{value: "some value 1"}, {value: "some value 2"}],
    result = [array1, array2].reduce(
        (r, a) => (a.forEach((o, i) => Object.assign(r[i] = r[i] || {}, o)), r),
        []
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: has some oddity where it combines props, beyond me: https://playcode.io/627249/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, what result do you expect?

Comment: sorry dint meant to hijack your answer (was best I found). see pen again added a comment

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, you need something different, because you need no merging at the same index, instead, you need (presumably) to merge by key. the last empty object is irritating. what should happen if you have more than one property? (just to mention ... maybe a new question would be best ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy modifying the actual objects within `arr1`, you could do something simple, like:

```
arr1.forEach((item, i) => item.value = arr2[i].value)
```

If you don't want to modify the original arrays, you can use `Object.assign` to build a new object:

```
arr1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i]))
```

Comment: What if the object in second array have other properties different that `value` or multiple properties?

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript map function.

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
var arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

var result = arr1.map(function(e, i) {
  return [e, arr2[i]];
});
```

See [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign` to achieve this where you do not need to depend on the key name for the object which is `value` in your case. You can use the code with more flexibility on properties name:

```js
let arr1 = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png"}, {image: "some_image_url_2.png"}]

let arr2 = [{value: "some value 1"}, {value: "some value 2"}]

let res = [];
arr1.forEach(function(obj, index){
  let newObj = Object.assign(obj, arr2[index])
  res.push(newObj);
});

console.log(res);
```

The main advantage of using `Object.assign` is that it will allow you to merge object with multiple properties like:

```js
let arr1 = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png"}, {image: "some_image_url_2.png"}]

let arr2 = [{value: "some value 1", anotherValue: 'anotherValue1'}, {value: "some value 2",  anotherValue: 'anotherValue2'}]

let res = [];
arr1.forEach(function(obj, index){
  let newObj = Object.assign(obj, arr2[index])
  res.push(newObj);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses typescript and arrow notation. You only need one line:

```
let result = arr1.map((item, index) => ({...item, ...arr2[index]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two arrays without removing the duplicates:

**ES6 using destructuring**

```
const arr1 = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png"}, {image: "some_image_url_2.png"}];
const arr2 = [{value: "some value 1"}, {value: "some value 2"}]
const arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2];
```

**ES5 using concat**

```
const arr1 = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png"}, {image: "some_image_url_2.png"}];
const arr2 = [{value: "some value 1"}, {value: "some value 2"}];
arr2.concat(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be workable like:

```
let arr1 = [{image: "some_image_url_1.png"}, {image: "some_image_url_2.png"}]
let arr2 = [{value: "some value 1"}, {value: "some value 2"}]
let merged = arr1.concat(arr2);
```